# Linux 5.16.7 device driver: ERROR: modpost: "__unregister_chrdev" undefined

Tags: c, makefile, linux-device-driver, linux

Currently I'm messing around with Linux kernel drivers
because I'm bored and I am currently going off online
resources and trying to learn how to make a basic char
device driver

Here's what I got so far:

```c
// src/hello.c

#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/export.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static unsigned int chdev_major = 254;
static const char *chdev_name   = "ari";

ssize_t chdev_file_read(struct file *a, char *b, size_t c, loff_t *d) {
    return 0;
}

static const struct file_operations chdev_opts = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .read  = chdev_file_read,
};

int register_device(void) {
    int result = 0;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Called register_device()\n");
    result = register_chrdev(chdev_major, chdev_name, &chdev_opts);

    if (result < 0) {
        printk(KERN_WARNING
               "Driver: failed to register chdev %s major=%u, err=%i\n",
               chdev_name, chdev_major, result);
        return result;
    }

    chdev_major = result;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Driver: registered chdev %s with major=%u\n", chdev_name,
           chdev_major);

    return 0;
}

void unregister_device(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Driver: unregistering device %s major=%u\n", chdev_name,
           chdev_major);

    if (chdev_major != 0)
        unregister_chrdev(chdev_major, chdev_name);
}

int __init ari_init(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Enter: driver\n");
    register_device();
    return 0;
}

void __exit ari_exit(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Exit: driver\n");
    unregister_device();
}

module_init(ari_init);
module_exit(ari_exit);
```

And my Makefile:

```
obj-m := src/hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean

install:
    insmod src/hello.ko

remove:
    rmmod src/hello.ko
```

Seems like everything is fine in both my code and my
makefile from what I see in...

- Online resources
- Reading the source code of the headers itself

But it's not(?), I try to compile it and I get this:

```bash
ari@ari-gentoo a % make
make -C /lib/modules/5.16.7/build M=/home/ari/a modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ari/Kernel/linux-5.16.7'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: clang version 13.0.1
  You are using:           clang version 14.0.4
  CC [M]  /home/ari/a/src/hello.o
  MODPOST /home/ari/a/Module.symvers
ERROR: modpost: "__unregister_chrdev" [/home/ari/a/src/hello.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "__register_chrdev" [/home/ari/a/src/hello.ko] undefined!
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:134: /home/ari/a/Module.symvers] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file '/home/ari/a/Module.symvers'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1745: modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ari/Kernel/linux-5.16.7'
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2
```

Exit code: 2

Seems like the main errors are:

```bash
ERROR: modpost: "__unregister_chrdev" [/home/ari/a/src/hello.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "__register_chrdev" [/home/ari/a/src/hello.ko] undefined!
```

Which I know that they're defined as I included `linux/fs.h`
and in it I see those symbols:

In directory `/lib/modules/5.16.7/build`, path: `include/linux/fs.h`,
line 2793-2810:

```c
extern int __register_chrdev(unsigned int major, unsigned int baseminor,
                 unsigned int count, const char *name,
                 const struct file_operations *fops);
extern void __unregister_chrdev(unsigned int major, unsigned int baseminor,
                unsigned int count, const char *name);
extern void unregister_chrdev_region(dev_t, unsigned);
extern void chrdev_show(struct seq_file *,off_t);

static inline int register_chrdev(unsigned int major, const char *name,
                  const struct file_operations *fops)
{
    return __register_chrdev(major, 0, 256, name, fops);
}

static inline void unregister_chrdev(unsigned int major, const char *name)
{
    __unregister_chrdev(major, 0, 256, name);
}
```

It's obviously there, I don't see the issue nor can I figure it out,
what's wrong?

Comment: It's very likely something to do with using the `src/` prefix for files referenced by the Makefile.

Comment: Try `obj-m := hello.o` `hello-y := src/hello.o`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Didn't work: make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'hello.o', needed by 'modules.order'.  Stop.

Comment: Does `grep register_chrdev /lib/modules/5.16.7/build/Modules.symvers` show the exported symbols `__unregister_chrdev`, `__register_chrdev`, `register_chrdev_region` and `unregister_chrdev_region`?

Comment: @IanAbbott: Instead of `hello-y` the variable should be named as `hello-objs`: exactly `-objs` suffixed variable denotes list of objects for a kernel module.

Comment: @IanAbbott 1544:0x00000000 unregister_chrdev_region vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm very confused what you mean

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have also used `hello-objs` in the past, but [this](https://docs.kernel.org/kbuild/modules.html#creating-a-kbuild-file-for-an-external-module) suggests it should be `hello-y`.

Comment: @Ari157 That grep output doesn't look correct. The address looks strange and I would have expected 4 pattern matches for "register_chrdev" (register_chrdev_region, unregister_chrdev_region, __register_chrdev, and __unregister_chrdev).